# Why can't I delete this file?

Tags: java, file, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to make a file delete after it has 20 characters in it. I have looked at every single Stack Overflow question about this, and no answer worked. I have looked every where, and nothing works. `File.delete();` does not work for me. It writes a file, and every time a button is pressed it adds a "1" to it. If there are 20 1's, than it needs to delete the file.

Sample Code:

```
String fileName1 = "data1.txt";
try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName1, true);
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
        bw.write("1");
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StudentRandomizerJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(StudentRandomizerJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("data1.txt"));
    String scannerData1 = scanner.nextLine();
    if (scannerData1.equals("11111111111111111111")) {
        //In here is where its supposed to delete the file.
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(StudentRandomizerJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried closing the `Scanner` object then trying to delete the file? This might cause an error because of a resource is accessing it.

Comment: Have you tried closing the `Scanner`/`FileReader` which probably has a read lock on the file first, before closing it...?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes I have, didn't work.

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: @DaveNewton By that I mean it doesn't delete the requested file.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Exceptions? You say `In here is where its supposed to delete the file.` can you actually add in this code so we can help debugging? `File.delete()` should return a boolean, whether or not the file was deleted, what is the return value? Voting to close for lack of context.

Comment: First: move the FileWriter `fw` into the try-with-resources block; Second: you don't need to call `bw.close();` manually. Third: make sure you closed the scanner before you try to delete the file. If all this is done: update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work okay for me...

```
for (int index = 0; index < 50; index++) {
    String fileName1 = "data1.txt";

    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName1, true))) {
        bw.write("1");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    boolean deleteMe = false;
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("data1.txt"))) {
        String scannerData1 = scanner.nextLine();

        if (scannerData1.length() >= 20) {
            deleteMe = true;
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (deleteMe) {
        File file = new File(fileName1);
        if (!file.delete()) {
            System.out.println("!! Could not delete " + file);
        } else {
            System.out.println(file + " was deleted");
        }
        System.out.println(file + " exists = " + file.exists());
    }
}
```

Prints

```
data1.txt was deleted
data1.txt exists = false
data1.txt was deleted
data1.txt exists = false
```

Maybe you need to check to see if you have the correct permissions to delete the file (but if you have write permissions, you should be able to delete it) and you're deleting the file you think you're deleting

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly! :)